# UI design with GWT

Tags: gwt, user-interface, integration

I'm hiring a designer to build UI for my web application. However I'm completely lost about how to integrate the design he will deliver to me with the GWT web application.

There are plenty of ways to build a UI in GWT. I believe the best choice for this case would be the UI binder, where I can use HTML to build the pages. However GWT widgets like textbox, dropdown, buttons, etc. have their own CSS that is not the same css of the page. So I believe this integration is a little bit confusing.

Am I correct about the difficulty of this task? Is there a proper way to do that (maybe creating a GWT theme)? Should I hire someone to do this integration? If yes, what is the kind of professional I'm looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar situation at work once. If you use [ui:Binder](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html), your web designer can develop most of the user interface using HTML and CSS, languages they would already know. There might be a little integration work to be done, but most of the application's UI can be built in a traditional, declarative way.

Note that there are some annoyances here. For some of the components, it's easier to use a GWT widget rather than a pure HTML element. However, GWT sometimes converts this to odd HTML, so it'll take some time for the designer to learn how GWT displays widgets and modify the style sheets accordingly.

Comment: Both of you need to become familiar with Ui:Binder. It is an amazing feature. Read the docs closely because you can do some cool stuff when you integrate UiBinder. [UiBinder](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html). Pay attention to [programmatic access](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Programmatic_access) and the external resources section

Comment: It took me (code) and Dan (design) about a month to get to a comfortable place for both of us with UiBinder, but it's really paying off now.  Converting from non-uibinder to uibinder was arduous in some situations, especially where CssResource injection & combination is necessary, but ultimately also worth it.

Comment: It's exactly the GWT widgets that makes me worry! I don't think I'll be using complex GWT widgets, but probably GWT textbox, dropdown, sliders and buttons. When the designer makes the UI, he will change the appearance of those widgets. I need to embed this new appearance to the widgets of my application. Is it easy to to that? Or it's something that involves changing those `.GWT-nameOfTheComponent` styles?

Comment: It's really not _that_ complicated. Your designer will just need to learn what the widgets look like in HTML and modify the CSS to work with that. It probably won't require massive changes and won't be a huge challenge.

Answer (score 0):

You can override any of the gwt style names in uibinder.  Also, there is a list of gwt styles that you can override in css if you want to do it that way. Of course you don't have to create gwt widgets for anything that doesn't have code interaction, which just leaves plain html and styles inside the uibinder.  Uibinder is designed to handle the exact division of tasks you are trying to set up.